# Html - Show a document .odt

Tags: html

There is an easy way to display an odt document in html?

With pdf extension is like:

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="FILE_URL" type="FILE_CONTENT_TYPE">
    <embed src="FILE_URL" type="FILE_CONTENT_TYPE" />
</object>
```

I would like to know if I can do something similar for .odt documents. Thanks!

Comment: With PDFs that only works if the browser can display PDFs natively, or there is a browser plugin for this installed. I don’t know of any browsers that could display ODT by default, but there seem to be plugins/extensions available, https://www.google.com/search?q=odt+browser+plugin Of course that won’t help you much, if you need this on a public site, where you can’t necessarily expect the users to have something like this installed.

Comment: are you ok with converting odt to html ?

Comment: @CBroe Right! I need it in a public site. Thank you.

Comment: @niceman Thanks but it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: @ricopo but if you convert odt to html you can show that html, the only concerns I'd have is to find some tool/library to do the conversion and whether it will be precise or not(and maybe performance too :( )

Comment: @niceman I just asked if you knew an easy way to do this but for now I'll try this [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) thanks.